# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

Throwing an error showing d is undefined. 
full text is: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference.
I cannot understand why it is not showing data. in database it has two records.

here is the HTMl, a button

**HTML**

```
<h3>Load Data</h3>
    <input id="btnLoadData" type="button" value="Load Database" onclick="GetCompanies()" />
    <div id="UpdatePanel">

    </div>
```

here is ajax call

**Ajax call with jQuery**

```
function GetCompanies() {
            $("#UpdatePanel").html("<div style='text-align:center'>Please Wait</div>")
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCompanies",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError

            });
        }

        function onSuccess(data) {
            var tableContent = "<table border='0'>" +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>Rank</td>" +
                "<td>Company Name</td>" +
                "<td>Revenue</td>" +
                "<td>Industry</td>" +
                "</tr>";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) { //d is undefined 
                tableContent+= 
                    "<tr>" +
                "<td>"+data.d[i].Rank+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+data.d[i].CompanyName+"</td>" +
                "<td>"+data.d[i].Revenue+"</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.d[i].Industry + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
            }
            tableContent += "</table>";
            $("#UpdatePanel").html(tableContent);
        }

        function onError(data) {

        }
```

**Back-end Code**

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static List<TopCompany> GetCompanies()
        {
            List<TopCompany> allCompany = new List<TopCompany>();
            using (MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {
                allCompany = db.TopCompanies.ToList();
            }
            return allCompany;
         }
```

required assistance to figure out the error.

Comment: check what is coming in `data` use `console.log(data)` or check your network tab for response

Comment: data return Object .. in Message Property it says "Authentication Failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by commenting the following statement

```
 // settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetCompanies() {
        $("#UpdatePanel").html("<div style='text-align:center'>Please Wait</div>")
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCompanies",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError

        });
    }

    function onSuccess(data) {
        var tableContent = "<table border='0'>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>Rank</td>" +
            "<td>Company Name</td>" +
            "<td>Revenue</td>" +
            "<td>Industry</td>" +
            "</tr>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //d is undefined 
            tableContent+= 
                "<tr>" +
            "<td>"+data[i].Rank+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+data[i].CompanyName+"</td>" +
            "<td>"+data[i].Revenue+"</td>" +
            "<td>" + data[i].Industry + "</td>" +
            "</tr>";
        }
        tableContent += "</table>";
        $("#UpdatePanel").html(tableContent);
    }

    function onError(data) {

    }
```

Comment: this only returned header of table not data